# a java script error in conditional statement

Tags: javascript, html, upload, field

I got an error in this what is the problem can any body help me I try top make when select a type of company_sign it open name of the manager and the position of this person to field it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function showfield(name)
if(name=='company_sing_1'){
    document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML='Manager Name 1: <input type="text" name="manaager_name" /><input type="text" name="manaager_position" />';
}else if(name=='company_sing_2'){
    document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML='Manager Name 2: <input type="text" name="manaager_name" /><input type="text" name="manaager_position" />';
}else if(name=='company_sing_3'){
    document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML='Manager Name 3: <input type="text" name="manaager_name" /><input type="text" name="manaager_position" />';
} else {
    else document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML='';
}

</script>

<select name="upload_type"  onchange="showfield(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
<option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Please Select Type Of Upload</option>
<option value="company_logo">Add A Logo</option>
<option value="company_logo_2">Add Second Logo</option>
<option value="company_logo_2">Add Third Logo</option>
<option value="company_sing_1">Add Sign For Manager 1</option>
<option value="company_sing_2">Add Sign For Manager 2</option>
<option value="company_sing_3">Add Sign For Manager 3</option>
</select><BR /><BR />
<div id="div1"></div></BR></BR>
```

Comment: The opening and closing braces for the function `showfield` is missing.

Comment: Surround your function body with braces: `function showfield(name) { ... }`

Comment: when I add braces it give me error at the end

Comment: else document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML=''; in this line give me error when put the braces...

Comment: thank for your help some tımes we forget stupıd things when we dont sleep for a long time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed the `{}` braces for your function

```
function showfield(name){
if(name=='company_sing_1'){
    document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML='Manager Name 1: <input type="text" name="manaager_name" /><input type="text" name="manaager_position" />';
}else if(name=='company_sing_2'){
    document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML='Manager Name 2: <input type="text" name="manaager_name" /><input type="text" name="manaager_position" />';
}else if(name=='company_sing_3'){
    document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML='Manager Name 3: <input type="text" name="manaager_name" /><input type="text" name="manaager_position" />';
} else {
    else document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML='';
}
}
```

Comment: it give me error at end of    else document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML='';

Comment: you have `else` without `if` inside last `else` loop

Comment: remove `else` before `document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML='';`